# AWK unexpected substr() behavior

Tags: awk

Using AWK I'd like to process this text:

```
J.Nawrocki & W.Complak
```

Into:

```
Nawrocki J. & Complak W.
```

I've got:

```
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
if ($i ~ /[A-Z]\.[A-Z][a-z]*/)
    {
    len=length($i);
    name=substr($i,1,2);
    surname=substr($i,3,len);
    printf("%s %s",surname,name);
    }
else printf("%s",$i);
}
printf("\n");
}
```

However I'm getting only

```
 W.rocki J.&Complak
```

(first sign is a space). Why is the " W." overwriting the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following script:

```
{ 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
        if ($i ~ /[A-Z]\.[A-Z][a-z]*/)
        {
            len=length($i)
            name=substr($i,1,2)
            surname=substr($i,3)
            $i= surname" "name
        }
    }
    print 
}
```

Notice that:

- `printf` does not need parenthesis around its argument..
- `substr()` does not need three parameters when you extract the rest of the string..
- There is no need to put semicolons after statements unless there are more than one on a line..

**Update**

If you are using dos line endings, you can either

- put `RS='\r\n'`, or
- convert the file to unix format first, using `dos2unix`

Comment: I'm still getting " W.rocki J. & Complak" :/

Comment: @uluroki Strange.. It works fine for me. Which version of `awk` are you using? I am using Gnu Awk version 3.1.8. By the way, your original code also worked for me :)

Comment: GNU Awk 4.0.1, Debian 7.2 64bit. It doesn't make any sense :(

Comment: @uluroki What file format are you using? Unix or dos? Note, that awk does not handle dos line ending (`\r\n`) very well..

Comment: Yes I am using dos line ending. I also tried using awk 'split()' but it does not work for me either. BTW: I copy-pasted your code and executed, and it failed :/

Comment: @uluroki If you are using dos line endings, that is probably the reason for the problems.. Try converting your file using `dos2unix` or `fromdos` ..

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F' & ' -v OFS=" & " '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){split($i,a,".");$i=a[2]"."a[1]}}7'
```

your example:

```
kent$  echo 'J.Nawrocki & W.Complak'|awk -F' & ' -v OFS=" & " '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ split($i,a,".");$i=a[2]" "a[1]"."}}7' 
Nawrocki J. & Complak W.
```

Comment: This would work, if the iput was always the same. But there can be another line with a more or less random set of words, and no '&'.

Answer (score 1):

Glad it turned out to be a line-ending thing (your original also worked fine for me on a mac).  As a personal exercise, I devised a sed approach, which is below, in case you find it useful in other contexts.

The logic of your current code doesn't take into account the possibility of multiple initials, names with prepositions (e.g. A. von Humboldt), etc.  For what it's worth, here's a sed approach with the same constraints:

```
echo "J.Nawrocki & W.Complak" | sed -E 's/([A-Z]\.)([A-Z][a-z]*)/\2 \1/g'
```

one that takes any number of initials:

```
echo "J.A.Nawrocki & W.Complak" | sed -E 's/(([A-Z]\.)+)([A-Z][a-z]*)/\3 \1/g'
```

and one that takes surnames that can have a preceding preposition (with or without a space):

```
echo "J.A.Nawrocki & W.von Complak" | sed -E 's/(([A-Z]\.)+)([a-z]*[[:space:]]?[A-Z][a-z]*)/\3 \1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

mawk '{sub(/J.Nawrocki & W.Complak/, "Nawrocki J. \& Complak W.")}1'file 
Nawrocki J. & Complak W.